# Proving a specific set is open

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $1\leq g_1\leq ...\leq g_r\leq d$ and define the set

$D(g_1,...,g_r)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{++}_d: \overline x_{g_l+1}<\overline x_{g_l}\ \text{for any}  \ l=1,...,r-1\}$,

where the set $\mathbb{R}^{++}_d$ is the set of all d-dimensional real vectors with strictly positive components and $\overline x$ has the same entries as $x$, ordered in a nonincreasing order. We have to prove that this set is open, meaning we have to show that for every $x$ in $D(g_1,...,g_r)$ there exists a d-ball $B_r(x)\subset D(g_1,...,g_r)$ for some $r>0$. The double usage of $r$ should not cause confusion, I hope.

My idea is as follows.

Wlog assume $x=\overline x$, since the set is symmetric. Define $r=(\min_{l=1,...,r-1} x_{g_l}-x_{g_l+1})\wedge x_d$. We take the minimum with $x_d$ to ensure that $B_r(x)\subset \mathbb{R}^{++}_d$. Now, I'm pretty sure this $r$ should suffice, but I'm looking for a simple argument. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

With "wlog" you have glossed over the essential part: We have to prove that the sorting map $$\sigma:\quad {\mathbb R}^d\to{\mathbb R}^d\ ,\qquad x\mapsto \bar x$$ is continuous as a vector-valued function.

(The rest is easy: The sets
$$Q_l:=\bigl\{y\in {\mathbb R}^d\ \bigm|\,y_{g_l+1}<y_{g_l}\bigr\}\qquad(1\leq l\leq r-1)$$
are obviously open in ${\mathbb R}^d$, and so is their intersection.)

The continuity of the sorting map $\sigma$ can be proven as follows:

Let a point $a\in{\mathbb R}^d$ be given. Since only the values of the $a_k$ are used in the argument, and not their original order in the list, we may as well assume $a=\bar a$. Fix a $j\in[d]$, and put $a_j=:\alpha$.  If $\alpha$ is an intermediate value in the list of values there are $\alpha'>\alpha$ and $\alpha''<\alpha$, as well as $j'<j$ and $j''>j$ such that
$$a_1\geq\ldots\geq a_{j'}=\alpha', \qquad a_k=\alpha\quad (j'<k<j''),\qquad \alpha''=a_{j''}\geq\ldots\geq a_d\ .$$
If $\alpha$ is an end-value then the $'$-part or the $''$-part will be missing here, and the following argument has to be slightly adapted.

Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. We shall show that $|\bar x_j-\bar a_j|=|\bar x_j- \alpha|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ in a suitable neighbohood of $a$. Choose
$$\delta<\min\left\{\epsilon, {\alpha'-\alpha\over2}, {\alpha-\alpha''\over2}\right\}\ .$$
Consider now a point $x$ with $|x_k-a_k|<\delta$ $(1\leq k\leq d)$. Then
$$x_k>\alpha'-\delta \quad(1\leq k\leq j'),\qquad x_k<\alpha''+\delta\quad(j''\leq k\leq d)\ ,$$ and
$$ |x_k-\alpha|<\delta\quad(j'<k<j'')\ .$$
It follows that 
$$\bar x_k>\alpha'-\epsilon \quad(1\leq k\leq j'),\qquad \bar x_k<\alpha''+\delta\quad(j''\leq k\leq d)\ ,$$
and
$$|\bar x_k-\alpha|<\delta\quad(j'<k<j'')\ ,$$
in particular $|\bar x_j-\alpha|<\delta<\epsilon$.

This shows that for each $j\in[d]$ and each point $a\in{\mathbb R}^d$ the function $x\mapsto \bar x_j$ is continuous at $a$, hence proves  that $\sigma$ is continuous.

Comment: So basically, we use the fact that the preimage of an open set is open, if the function is continuous. But shouldn't $Q_l$ be then defined as a subset of vectors with nonincreasing order?

Comment: @ArkhamKnight: I don't think so. The nonincreasing order comes from the map $\sigma$, and not from the definition of openness.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for your explaination.

Comment: I am struggling to prove the continuity of the map $\sigma$. Do you have suggestion, which method I should use? I already tried to porve it with the epsilon-delta definition and via the limit definition.